# Manage multi tabs (pages) in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, tabs

I want to manage multiple page or tabs in UIWebView like default iPhone Safari See Screen shot for better understand :

http://s14.postimg.org/xie4imi35/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_shot_24_May_2014_7_56_03_PM.png

Is that possible to manage this in UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

Three things I want to tell you here:

1. See Answer for multi tab in UIWebView [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158531/multi-tab-web-browsers-with-uiwebview-on-ios).
2. Look at [HGPageScrollView](https://github.com/100grams/HGPageScrollView) library and [WKPagesCollectionView](https://github.com/adow/WKPagesCollectionView) on Github.
3. I saw that in UINavigationController when we move from ParentViewController to ChildViewController and then move back again state of Parent view is maintained. I am trying to use that in implementing multi tabs in UIWebView.