# Adding a webview for each tab in UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, xamarin, webview, uiviewcontroller

How do I add a web view for each of these tabs in my UIViewController?

```
public class TabController: UITabBarController
{
    UIViewController tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4, tab5, tab6, tab7;

    public TabController()
    {
        tab1 = new UIViewController();
        tab1.Title = "Test";
        tab1.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;



        tab2 = new UIViewController();
        tab2.Title = "Test2";
        tab2.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;

        tab3 = new UIViewController();
        tab3.Title = "Test3";
        tab3.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

        tab4 = new UIViewController();
        tab4.Title = "Test4";
        tab4.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

        tab5 = new UIViewController();
        tab5.Title = "Test5";
        tab5.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

        tab6 = new UIViewController();
        tab6.Title = "Test6";
        tab6.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

        tab7 = new UIViewController();
        tab7.Title = "Test7";
        tab7.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;




        var UIViewController = new UIViewController[] {
                            tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4, tab5, tab6, tab7
    };


        tab1.TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem(UITabBarSystemItem.Favorites, 0);

        ViewControllers = UIViewController;
    }
}
```

So for each tab, instead of "tab1.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;", it
should be:
Webview + Title + Link so that each tab has a different page?

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: For each tab, it must have a web view, each web view will have a link and title so that when I click on a tab let's call it Test1(title), it'll open a web view with a certain link, then the same for the rest of the tabs.

Comment: then drag viewcontroller in storyboard -> drag webview and use this viewcontroller in appdelegate .

Comment: Basically I want to do what this guy has done:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158531/multi-tab-web-browsers-with-uiwebview-on-ios

I have each tab associated with a different child UIViewController, but how do I add a UIWebView for each of these with the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to do this using the storyboard and assigning the viewcontroller classes to your tabs. However if you want to do it programatically I suppose you would need to do the following:

```
    tab7 = new UIViewController();
    tab7.Title = "Test7";
    tab7.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
    //Create a webview
    UIWebView webView = new UIWebView(View.Bounds); //Takes size as a constructor parameter
    //Set it's navigation location
    webView.Navigate(new URI("www.whatever.co.uk"));
    //Add the webview to the subviews of your UIViewController
    tab7.View.AddSubview(webView);
```

You'd do this for each tab.

On a side note it's worth mentioning that apples guidelines for application submissions to their store does tend to frown upon applications which are just web site representations, so worth bearing that in mind. The application must be able to do more than apples web browser could.

Comment: Just tried it, and when I declare the UIWebView it says that "Default constructor that initializes a new instance of this class with no parameters".

Comment: apologies, my mistake, I forgot that the webview takes the size as a parameter for its constructor, I've amended my answer so it should work correctly now.

Comment: Thanks for the help but on Navigate, I get the error "UIWebView" does not contain a definition for 'Navigate' and for "URI" I get, the type or namespace 'URI' could not be found .. will try to google these issues for now but if you know of a way to fix these please let me know. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Got it working by doing this: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/web_view/load_a_web_page/  .. thanks for the idea!